# Expand [ssms] into [sql-server-management-studio]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I'd like to propose renaming [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) to [sql-server-management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-management-studio). The original tag was created when tags were limited to 25 characters, but I see no reason to keep the abbreviation now that the limit has been increased.

Comment: when i search for it, i tend to google "ssms" simply because it is shorter.  Maybe instead of renaming, just creating a new tag for [tag:sql-server-management-studio] and then proposing [tag:ssms] be made a synonym of the new tag,

Comment: @psubsee2003 The non-hyphenated version is already a synonym and will return the parent tag, because we exclude hyphens when running tag searches.

Comment: (Common shortenings like *Management Studio* and *Server Management Studio* are already synonyms.)

Comment: @animuson right but if we take this request and rename ssms to sql-server-management-studio, what will be returned if someone types ssms?  Since it is not a synonym, nothing right?  Which is why i expanded the initial proposal, create a hyphened version to be the main tag and make ssms a synonym

Answer (score 1):

What benefit is derived over renaming, as opposed to simply adding the synonym `sql-server-management-studio` to the `ssms` tag? You can do that yourself, right now, if you have enough rep in the latter tag.

There certainly isn't currently a discoverability problem, because if you type `sql-server-management-studio` in the tags box you get suggested `ssms` due to one of its existing synonyms being `sqlservermanagementstudio`.